# How to unselect the grid record in kendoui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am selecting the listview record on databound event. I have written the following code in databound

```
       var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
       grid.select(grid.tbody.find(">tr:first"));
```

Now i want to deselect the grid dynamically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`clearSelection`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-clearSelection):

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.clearSelection();
```

Comment: How to unselect a single row among multiple rows?

Comment: `Clears the currently selected table *rows* or *cells*` , so I am assuming OP meant record(s) .  @GangadharJannu : currently this is not supported by the `clearSelection`.

Comment: @RyBolt Thanks for your comments. Using custom function in databound event I was able to select multiple rows using class

Answer (score 4):

kendo grid has a property called `selectable:true`..this would select the entire row when clicked upon and to de-select the row simply press ctrl+the row which is selected..